# Dependent variables

Tags: excel

I am trying to create a calculator based off of a table containing a whole bunch of data.  The table contains manufacturers (about 12), each manufacturer has about 4 models, each model comes in about 6 sizes, and each size has 2 or 3 pressure ratings.  I have made cascading drop down lists on my calculator to choose the make, model, size and pressure rating, and now I would like to pull the information I need from the table based upon the choices that were made in the drop down lists.  What would the easiest way of achieving this?

Comment: Look for `dependent drop down list excel` and `data validation` in Google or in StackOverflow.

Comment: please include the code in your question...

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing any specifics, I might recommend to turn your data into named sets either through tables or named ranges, etc. Name each data set according to your dropdown values then use something like SUM(INDIRECT("'"&SHEETNAME&"'"&"!"&DSN)

Where SHEETNAME is the name of the worksheet your dropdown exists on and DSN is the cell address of the dropdown which contains the specific Data Set Name you want to calculate. This basically creates a calculation for the named range specified by the dropdown: SUM(NamedRange)

If you do this, you'll need to either write a procedure to update your ranges or manually keep your ranges updated as data changes.